# Mocha sidebar vscode extension is not auto refreshing the tests

Tags: mocha.js, mocha-sidebar

I have just installed the mocha-sidebar extension in vs code. I am using the following config in my settings.json file:

```
{
"mocha.files.glob": "test/**/*.spec.js",
"mocha.requires": [],
"mocha.env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "test"
},
"mocha.sideBarOptions": {
    "lens": true, 
    "decoration": true,
    "autoUpdateTime": 1000,
    "showDebugTestStatus": true 
}
```

}

If I click the green play button in the extension window it runs the tests correctly and shows the results in the sidebar. If I now update the test to make it fail the previously green circle next to the test changes to yellow, but nothing else happens.

I would expect the test to be shown with a red circle (failing), I would also expect the test in the test file to have a red dot next to the failing test, but this remains green.

I have to run the tests by pressing the green play button again from the sidebar.

The other thing I have noticed is that when a test fails, it reports the failure in the test file e.g. //expected a to equal a. But when the test is updated to pass the comment does not get removed and I have to switch files and then return to the test file which then seems to remove the comment.

Thanks in advance!